# Realm - RJSRealmDelegate.changes_available assert(0) causing crash

Tags: swift, react-native, realm

We are building a React-Native iOS app that needs to access our realms natively as well as via RN.

We have writing working correctly from our UI and can load the data in our background Swift service, but after the write, The changes_available method in js_realm.cpp is firing which contains assert(0) which is causing the app to crash/hang in debug.  What do we need to be doing to prevent that method from firing?

Answer (score 0):

Update: A release was just made (0.11.1) which should prevent this crash from occurring. Note that notifications across bindings have not yet been tested and may not work.

This method gets called when changes are made externally to a Realm from another process or thread. In your case it sounds like writes made from the swift apis are causing this method to get called. The ReactNative binding was written with the assumption that everything would be done from a single thread without considering the use of other language bindings being used simultaneously.

As is the only thing you can to do prevent this is to not make a write in Swift while a Realm is open in JS. One way to do this would be to call `Realm.close` after every use, although this may perform poorly.

In the near term we can also do a point release to remove the `assert(0)` - this will prevent the crash/hang, but notifications for changes made in Swift wont work without additional changes. Can't give an estimate of when we can get cross language notifications working properly.

Comment: This crash should no longer occur. Let us know how it goes.